# Polynomial output in the form of “x^n + an-1*x + a0” when input is n

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a polynomial in the form of `x^2 + a1*x + a0` if input number is `2,ο`, `x^3 + a2*x^2 + a1*x + a0` if input number is `3`, etc. My code only shows the output of `x^n + an-1*x + a0` regardless of given number.

The code is below:

```
def funct(num):
    for i in range(1,num):
         print(f"x^{num}+a{num-1}*x+a0")

    number = int(input("give me number"))
    funct(number)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't you need an `if´ somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
def funct(num):
    str0 = "a0"
    str1 = "a1x + a0"
    if num == 0:
      print(str0)
    elif num == 1:
      print(str1)
    else:
      str = str1
      for i in range(2,num):
        str = f"a{i}x^{i} + " + str
      print(f"x^{num} + " + str)
```

For num = 0, you simply return the constant term a0.

For num = 1, you have a linear expression which won't need to be shown as x^1, so we can simply write it as "a1x + a0"

For num = 2 onwards, we split it down as follows:

- The term with power = n should have co-efficient 1, so we separate that out
- The two smallest terms will simply be "a1x + a0", so we just reuse what we have for the num =1 case
- For all the terms in between, we loop through ther terms from 2 until num - 1, and put them in the desired format
- Finally, we put all these strings together to get the output in the desired format

Note that this code assumes that we are only dealing with positive integers. You will need to implement handling for other inputs according to your requirements.

Comment: No problem, you had the right idea, but were using the loop in the wrong way